# Can OpenVZ have SLES, CentOS, and OpenSuse guests?

Tags: linux, openvz

I have a SLES Xen Host and a CentOS Xen host, so I was wondering, if I would be able to migrate these Xen guests (CentOS 5, SLES 10, OpenSUSE 11) to OpenVZ?

None of the guests uses any kernel feaures.

Can OpenVZ handle all those on one OpenVZ host?

Comment: no kernel features?  wow!  didn't know Centos could work without network, disk, virtual memory, multitasking, pipes, threads, filesystems....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [article on HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-convert-physical-systems-and-xen-vms-into-openvz-containers-debian-etch) which details the transition of Xen-based containers to OpenVZ. Take note of the homogeneous parameter in which the author chose to use Debian as a common platform.

On a personal note: The option of migrating a Xen-based guest into a OpenVZ-based environment is very unstable and should be done so on an experimental basis. I strongly discourage this option if your Xen-based guests are flagged for production usage.

Hope you will find the article useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that howto, and the warning. It is for production, so I guess I'll follow your advice, and not to migrate.